# Automate Power BI Desktop Report

Tags: python, powerbi

I'm trying to automate the publishing or exporting of a Power BI graph report every Monday morning by running a Python script that would be started by a cron job or Windows task scheduler. I'm using the Python pbixrefresher script that I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/dubravcik/pbixrefresher-python/blob/master/pbixrefresher/pbixrefresher.py).

The Python automation script hasn't been updated since 2019 but mostly works when i run it:

```
c:\pbixrefresher\pbixrefresher>python pbixrefresher.py "C:\another folder\report1.pbix" --workspace "My workspace"
Starting Power BI
Waiting  15 sec
Identifying Power BI window
Refreshing
Waiting for refresh end (timeout in  30000 sec)
Saving
Publish
{'auto_id': 'KoPublishToGroupDialog', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'report1 - Power BI Desktop', WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.ca490a_r8_ad1, 6285010>, 'backend': 'uia'}
```

It isn't fully automated because it still prompts me if I want to save my changes, so I have to click "Save":

[image]

Even though I entered the --workspace argument, it still prompts me to Select workspace, and I have to choose "My workspace" and then click Select button:

[image]

Does anyone know what I need to change in the pbixrefresher.py script so that it accomplish these last steps?

- Automatically Click Save after it has refreshed the .pbix file
- Automatically Select "My workspace" if I choose to publish it to my Power BI online account.
- Automatically export as a pdf file to my computer, e.g. c:\monday_reports\report1.pdf

My Power BI Desktop Version is 2.112.1161.0 64 bit (December 2022) free version, running in Windows 10. I prefer to stick with the free version instead of upgrading to Pro or Ultimate license as Power BI Pro and Ultimate seem like overkill for achieving a fairly simple tasks. Also, I prefer not to use Power BI Report Server if at all possible. Or maybe there is an open source alternative of Power B.I. that would work better than my Power BI free version. Thanks.

Comment: The right way to achieve what you need is to publish the report to Power BI Service (a Free account is enough for what you do) and use [the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset) to refresh the report (or [schedule it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh)). Then the report will be up to date without re-publishing. To use the API to export it to file automatically, you will need a paid license (Premium or Embedded).

Comment: 100% agree with above comments. You should not be using that python repo for this. Nevermind the fact that Microsoft has a better approach for this, that repo has not been updated in nearly 4 years and specifically says it was tested on PBI Desktop June 2019, so even if worked then I wouldn't trust it nowadays.